# shuffle and edit columns in awk

Tags: awk

I want to shuffle and edit column 1 and put it as column 2. I want to keep only the part after "-" in column 1. 
I tried to shuffle with

```
  awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

in:

```
#9-297  TACCTGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTCCTC
#10-276 CACAGCGTTGGTGGTATAGTGGTTAGCCACC
```

out:

```
ACCTGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTCCTC 297
CACAGCGTTGGTGGTATAGTGGTTAGCCACC 276
```

Comment: you dropped the first *thymine*

Answer (score 3):

You can split the first column to an array on the delimiter "-", then print out the part of the array you want:

```
awk '{split($1, a, "-");print $2, a[2]}' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[-[:space:]]+' '{print $3, $2}' file
TACCTGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTCCTC 297
CACAGCGTTGGTGGTATAGTGGTTAGCCACC 276
```